# Fql facebook api queries

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
 var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/");
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            var requestString = "fql?q=SELECT status_id, message FROM status 
               WHERE uid=me()";

            byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);

            webRequest.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;

            var requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
            var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            var responseString = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

I am trying to get the status messages for my fb account above code throws bad request and this one using facebook api get request says invalid parameters

```
                string accessToken = ViewState["accessToken"].ToString();
            Facebook.FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            dynamic me = fb.Get("/me");

            var id = me.id;

            string query = "SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid=me()";

            var posts = fb.Get("/fql?q=SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid=me()");
```

Any help would be appreciated.. facebook giving me headbangings.. :\
and last thing is the query above works perfect in fql graph api simulator

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=uridfields%3Did%2Cname

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this: [Facebook Graph API - User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)
Under Connections you will find "Statuses".

In order to get an array of all you statuses, you have to call `/me/statuses?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`
You have to have got `read_stream` permission.

Hope I could help.

Edit:
In case of WinRT:
I would call Graph API in another way (don't know if it is better but it works too):

```
// Example Uri
Uri requestUri = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN");    

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);

string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return content;
```